# Как преобразовать единицы измерения в скрипте FastReport в сантиметры?

Tags: fastreport

При построении отчета мы задаем размер страницы шаблона и относительные положения элементов отчета в мм (например 297х210) и сантиметрах (например, типичная высота строки в шаблоне `0.50`). В то же время, все размеры и относительные положения элементов отчета при обращении из скрипта, задаются в каких-то других единицах (та же высота строки в шаблоне `0.50`, а в скрипте - `18.89765`).

Вопрос - что это за единицы измерения в скрипте, и как пересчитать их в сантиметры/миллиметры?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему, идет перевод из DPI (не нашел где задается, обычно 96) в мм. Соответственно, формула пересчета для мм:

```
Размер_в_скрипте = Размер_в_мм * 96 / 25.4
```